# First letter of first paragaph of a section with a different font

Tags: fonts, letters

The problem is that every first letter of the first paragaph in a section is in a different font than the rest. The O's for example are a lot slimmer than the rest, and this is really bad for me, visually.

How can I avoid this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\section{Introd}
\begin{texttt}
O ter yuio paos wqepo ,kert ekjt elkrt . \\

Osd oeir qowie sajd eoir qwpeo eori lqwjer.

\end{texttt}

\end{document}
```

[image: Strange O, good O]

Comment: Thats it, thank you. I used it a long time ago from an example to start learning, and never removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `texttt` environment; your code works with undesired results due to a casuality.

Remove the `texttt` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\section{Introd} 

O ter yuio paos wqepo ,kert ekjt elkrt .

Osd oeir qowie sajd eoir qwpeo eori lqwjer.


\end{document}
```

[image]
If you want mono-spaced font, you can use `\texttt{text}` or `{\ttfamily text}`.

Comment: Thats it, thank you. I used it a long time ago from an example to start learning, and never removed it.

Comment: @user50039 You're welcome! Don't forget that, now that you've received some answers and after a sensible wait, you can accept the answer that you consider best solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).